# Create a Color Map in Matplotlib via Hex Codes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a color map in Matplotlib so that I could pass it in `plt.get_cmap()`. Based on tutorials, I only see making color maps via RGB levels. But I have three (3) hex codes that I want to use in my chart. These are: `#f1a340`, `#f7f7f7`, and `#998ec3`.

Anybody experienced making a color map using Hex Codes?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend converting your hex values into RGB tuples, then adding them all to a list. you can then utilize the from_list() method of linearSegmentedColormap to create a unique color map

> LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list()

If you need more information you can use this as a reference:

https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/custom_cmap.html

Comment: Thanks for this. I just have another noob question...matplot is asking for the RGB tuples with values from 0 to 1. Like, example, the `#998ec3` would have an RGB value of `(153, 142, 195)`, but it seems different from the tutorial. It should look something like this:[(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)]

Comment: This is because the RGB tuple is expecting values on a 0-1 scale as opposed to 0-255, simply divide your values by 255 to get the corresponding value on the 0-1 scale